# Adding an element to a sub array of an array in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I want to create a mongodb document structure like below.

```
data:[[{a:b},{b:c}],[{e:f}],[{f:g},{j:h},{i:l}]]
```

This structure will allow me to add new sub array element, 4th one to the existing data array which contains three sub arrays in the above example, if required.

I am able to add new sub array element using below command from mongodb shell.

```
db.xyz.update({'id':'A01'},{$push:{data:[]}},{})
```

However, I am unable to findout solution for pushing data in to respective arrays. The following command is not working.

```
db.xyz.update({'id':'A01'},{$push:{data[0]:{$push:{a:b}}}},{})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single $push should be enough. Try this instead:

```
db.xyz.update({'id':'A01'}, {$push: {"data.0": {a: "b"}}})
```

result:

```
{
   "_id":ObjectId("586b907a4979a26deaacf4ad"),
   "data":[
      [
         {
            "a":"b"
         },
         {
            "b":"c"
         },
         {
            "a":"b"
         }
      ],
      [
         {
            "e":"f"
         }
      ],
      [
         {
            "f":"g"
         },
         {
            "j":"h"
         },
         {
            "i":"l"
         }
      ]
   ]
}
```

Comment: And for retrieving the first element of first array in data i am trying db.xyz.find({'id':'A01'},{data.0:{$slice:1}}) but unable to get it. i am getting all the array elements of first array while trying db.xyz.find({id:'A01'},{data:{$slice:1}}) how to get the first element of first array.

Comment: @SatyaNarayana you can do this like this:  db.xyz.aggregate([{$match: {_id: "A01"}}, {$project: {data: {$arrayElemAt: [{$arrayElemAt: ["$data", 0]}, 0]}}} ])